# Why $6$? Is this meant to be intuitive?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

What is this question asking?

Do you just simply count to number of 1's and 0's and then choose that integer, 6?

> $$y=10^k+10^{k+1}+10^{k+2}$$
>
> In the equation above, $k$ is an integer. For what value of $k$ can $y$ be expressed as an integer whose digits consist of twice as many $0$'s as $1$'s?

[(original photo of question)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cECGz.png)

Comment: Hint: $10^k + 10^{k+1} + 10^{k+2} = 10^k (1 + 10 + 100)$.

Comment: As long as you don't count zeros to the *left* of the ones.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ *Factor* $ $ it: $\,\ y \,=\, (10^2\!+10+1)10^k =\, 111\cdot 10^k =\, 111\overbrace{00\cdots00}^{\large k}$

**Remark** $\ $ Factorization often simplifies matters, esp. when the common factor is complicated (here an exponential). So, as a first start, one should always pull out obvious (complicated) factors to see if that lends any insight to the problem at hand. Let's consider another example

$$\begin{align} 0\, &=\, e^{(n+2)x}\!-3e^{(n+1)x}+2e^{nx}\\
&=\, e^{nx}(e^{2x}-3 e^x + 2)\\
&=\, e^{nx}(e^{x}\!-2)(e^x\! - 1)
\end{align}\qquad$$

and now the equation is very easy to solve. Notice how factoring out the $\,e^{nx}\,$ allowed us to more easily recognize the easily factorable quadratic cofactor

Answer (score 1):

Each of the powers of $10$ will contribute a single $1$ digit, so there will be $3\ 1$'s in total.  You therefore need $6$ zeros, which you get if $k=6$, because $10^6$ ends in $6\ 0$'s

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

In decimal form $y$ starts with $111\dots$ and the other digits are zeros.